# Cannot convert string to date in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have datetime:

```
string validDate = formCollection["ValidDate"];
```

The ValidDate value is:

```
06/24/2014
```

If I want to convert `validDate` to `ir.ValidDate` I get an exception.

```
InterestRate ir = new InterestRate();

ir.ValidDate = Convert.ToDateTime(validDate);
```

Exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I tried the below. However still get exception:

```
DateTime resultDate = DateTime.ParseExact(validDate , "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

What did I miss exactly?

Comment: According to your example, it is "MM/dd/yyyy" and not "dd/MM/yyyy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one :
and change the format of your date `dd/MM/yyyy` to `MM/dd/yyyy`

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(validDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your date is in format `MM/dd/yyyy` (06/24/2014), but you're trying to parse it as `dd/MM/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   public class Employee
    {

        public DateTime DateOfJoining { get; set; }

    }

    DateOfJoining = DateTime.Parse("05/02/2014"),
```